# Find the nature of the curve

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given: $x=t^2+t+1, y=t^2-t+1$

Find the nature of the curve.

My approach: I was trying to relate $x$ and $y$. However I haven't been able to. Please suggest some methods to solve such kind of questions.

Comment: What natures are there?

Comment: @GitGud I'd assume that he means the shape of the curve once graphed.

Comment: Can you do classification of quadratics, say with matrices and stuff? I mean, this thing seems to be a parabola...

Answer (score 0):

Would $x-y = 2t$ help you proceed? [Then you can plug $t = \frac{x-y}{2}$ back into one of the equations.]